# Asp.net web api with unity The type String cannot be constructed

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, unity-container

Hi I am crating a web api with unity dll and when i am integrating this first i have faced

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

error i have resolved it by adding:

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Http" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.0.0.0" newVersion="5.0.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

in the web config file and after that i run the application and 
i got the error as below

> The type String cannot be constructed. You must configure the container to supply this value.

Then i searched the internet and i have added:

```
[InjectionConstructor]
```

to the constructor and it doesnot resolves the issue 
I am using `ApiController` my controller code is as below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Practices.Unity;


namespace Check.Api.Controllers
{
    public class CommonController : ApiController
    {

        #region Variables
        /// <summary>
        /// Business layer of .
        /// </summary> 
        private IBLPIP _blPIP;
        private IBLCommon _blCommon;
        #endregion

        #region Constructor
        /// <summary>
        /// Constructor of Login API Controller
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="auth"></param>
         [InjectionConstructor]
        public CommonController( IBLCommon blCommon)
        {
            this._blCommon = blCommon;
        }
        #endregion

        #region Methods

        [HttpGet]
        public HttpResponseMessage Get_CountryList()
        {
            try
            {
                List<Country> CountryList = _blCommon.GetCountryList();
                return Request.CreateResponse<List<Country>>(HttpStatusCode.OK, CountryList);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                LogUtil.Error("LoginServiceController\\Login\n" + ex.Message);
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
            }
        }

        #endregion

    }
}
```

Any one please help me thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

> The type String cannot be constructed. You must configure the container to supply this value.

The error indicates that you are passing a string into the constructor of one or more of your classes (that you have not shown here).

The solution is to configure Unity to inject the string into your class.

```
public class SomeType : ISomeType
{
    private readonly string someString;
    public SomeType(string someString)
    {
        this.someString = someString;
    }
}

string someString = "This is a string value";
container.RegisterType<ISomeType, SomeType>(
    "someString", new InjectionConstructor(someString));
```

Strings and primitive types need to be injected manually because Unity has no idea of knowing *which* string you intend to inject.